# Running iptables on a rooted xoom (android 3 honeycomb)

Tags: java, android, chmod, iptables, su

I am trying to add some rules to filter network traffic from/to the device (Xoom WiFi) using iptables. The iptables command is located at /system/bin/iptables in the xoom device running android 3.0.1. I am abel add rules using the adb shell. However i can't seem to do the same through a android app.

**With SU**

(`su -c command`). The Xoom has been rooted. And iptables has been granted su permissions thougth the Superuser app(latest version, uptodate su binary):

iptables

> 07-18 09:00:32.990: DEBUG/su(17539): 10054 com.iptables executing 0
>   /system/bin/iptables using shell /system/bin/sh : sh 07-18
>   09:00:33.010: WARN/su(17546): request rejected (0->0
>   /system/bin/iptables)

chown

> 07-18 09:02:21.380: WARN/su(17594): request rejected (0->0
>   /system/bin/chmod)

**Without SU**

iptables

> no output. nothing happens. rules don't get added.

chown

> no output. works as expected!?!.

How i run the iptables command:

```
runCommand(new String[] { "su", "-c", "/system/bin/iptables", "-F" });
            runCommand(new String[] { "su", "-c", "/system/bin/iptables", "-A", "OUTPUT", "-d", "184.72.45.145", "-j", "ACCEPT" });
```

The method for running a command:

```
public static String runCommand(String[] ars) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ars);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(sCurrentLine);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I am hitting a wall. Any help highly appreciated. Thanks!